# How do I get geom_line to connect my desired points?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom

I am trying to plot reading time over a string of words, divided into 2 groups based on gender. I am able to create the following plot with the following code:

```
GA %>%
group_by(Gender) %>%
ggplot()+
aes(x=Word, y=Time, color=Gender)+
geom_point(stat = "summary", fun = "mean")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt6vj.png)`

I would like to add a `geom_line` to this image, that connects the points horizontally, with a separate line for each gender. However, when I use the following code, I get this image instead.

```
GA %>%
group_by(Gender) %>%
ggplot()+
aes(x=Word, y=Time, color=Gender)+
geom_point(stat = "summary", fun = "mean")+
geom_line()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8jhZ.png)`

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? Thank you so much in advance. I tried using the "group" aesthetic within aes().

Comment: Welcome to SO! You are on the right track with the `group` aes, i.e. try with `geom_line(aes(group = Gender))`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared via `dput()`. BTW: You can remove the group_by. This has no effect for a ggplot.

Comment: Thank you for this feedback. I tried with geom_line(aes(group = Gender)) to the same result. I will modify my original post to share a subset of the data for an example.

Comment: Aw. Sorry. My fault. As you are using `stat="summary"` in geom_point you have to do the same for `geom_line` (and use the `group` aes), i.e. try `geom_line(aes(group= Gender), stat = "summary", fun = "mean")`.

Comment: @stefan No problem, thanks so much! I just tried that and it worked! I am so, so, so grateful for your help!